# how to use case statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having students table.I want to give the grade.I am working on Oracle database.

If marks greater than 60 then “A”, If marks are less than  35 then fail, if marks are greater than 40 and less than 50 then “C”, If marks are greater than 50 and less than 60 then “B”.

Comment: `CASE WHEN mark > 60 THEN 'A' WHEN mark BETWEEN 40 AND 50 THEN 'C' WHEN ........ END`

Comment: @Lamak, You may want to adjust your between to `41 and 49` per OP criteria.

Comment: @WEI_DBA yeah, it was getting too long to write

Comment: What if `marks` is exactly 50 or 60? Or between 35 and 40?

Comment: There is a bug in your requirement: what if the marks are 50 or 60? Other than that: have a look at this article explaining case: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

Comment: the more correct term here is `case expression` in Oracle a `case statement` is a PL/SQL branching structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, last_name,
   ( CASE WHEN mark >= 60 THEN 'A'
          WHEN mark >= 50 THEN 'B'
          WHEN mark >= 40 THEN 'C'
          WHEN mark < 35 THEN 'F'
          ELSE '?'
          END ) grade
   FROM students;
```

By the way there's no info given about marks between 35 & 40, and equalities are assumed by me, also.

Comment: Cool.Thank you so much

Comment: You could simplify this by reordering the `when` options in descending order; then you wouldn't need the upper bounds.

Comment: @AlexPoole ok thanks, i've edited. To be able to answer quickly, i couldn't pay attention to ordering :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic also needs to figure out what to do with 60, 50, etc. Currently you don't include these in your logic. If for instance 60 and above is an A then you need `marks >= 60`

```
CASE 
  WHEN marks > 60 THEN 'A'
  WHEN marks > 50 and marks < 60 THEN 'B'
  WHEN marks > 40 and marks < 50 THEN 'C'
  WHEN marks < 35 THEN 'fail'
END
```

Comment: What happens when `marks` is exactly 60 or 50 or between 35 and 40?

Comment: @MT0 That's why I added he needs to decide which ones those will be included in.

Comment: It isn't defined by the stated requirements, so null for those scenarios seems reasonable *8-)